# Best practice to reload div on click and post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am not the greatest at jQuery and still learning bits and bobs.  I currently have the below function and I would like to expand on it to post data to `referrer-ajax2.php`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#clickthrough').click(function(){
        $('#declined').load('referrer-ajax2.php #declined2');
    });
});
```

Can I just add another function such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#clickthrough').click(function(){
    $('#declined').load('referrer-ajax.php2 #declined2', function() {
        $.post('referrer-ajax.php2', { company_selected: $('#refselect').val(), ref_date_from:  $('#ref_date_from').val(), ref_date_to:  $('#ref_date_to').val() },
    });
});
});
```

Is this the correct way to do things or is there a more sensible way?  Would this not reload the div and THEN post the data (which would be the wrong way round) I assume I can just switch the functions round?

Not really tried anything yet just looking to understand the correct way to do this and develop my knowledge of jQuery.

Appreciate your input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can add it but it should be first post, then load. Buf if you want to show something specific after you post something, just send what you want to show back and don't make another request (load) to get the updated content.

Comment: Thanks japrescott.  Could you please expand or send me a link regarding the 2nd part of your comment "just send what you want to show back and don't make another request (load) to get the updated content." So that I can have a read up please?  Not sure if this is valid to what I am looking to use this for.  The initial div is eg Items and the 2nd div is eg Item Properties rather than say a +1 button.

Comment: well, I see that you have 2 scripts on the server. One for handling your post and one for handling your load. When posting the data, you normally send back an "everything is okey, please continue". But in your case, after the post, you want to load something. So instead of sending "everything is okey", you could directly send back the information, that you would load from the "load-script". But since you appear to be a beginner, just play around with jquery and php and eventually you will understand what I wrote :) good luck